# var scoping and module calls in a cfc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

If I have a method in a CFC which needs to call in some legacy code via a module call (to perform some critical functionality) am I at risk for variable "bleeding"? For example:

```
<!--- in my cfc --->
<cffunction name="myFunc"> 

   <cfset var qData = "">
   <cfmodule template="some_legacy_code.cfm" attr1="hi" attr2="hello">
   <cfreturn qData>

</cffunction>


<!--- in some_legacy_code.cfm --->
<cfquery name="qData">
     select * from x
</cfquery>

<cfset caller.qData = qData>
```

By using caller.qData in this example am I polluting the variables scope of the calling CFC even though I've var scoped qData?

What is the best way for me to test this bleed over so I can "see it for myself" considering I can't easily readily replicate multiple simultaneous calls from different requests as a real application might encounter?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: My guess is that `caller.qData` in the module would refer to `variables.qData` in the CFC. You can dump the variables scope: `<cfdump var="#variables#" />` to check and make sure.

Comment: Good call and thank you. Figuring out how to test to be certain now, will post an update momentarily.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I could have searched first to find the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409797/can-cfmodule-return-values-to-callers-local-scope

Comment: FYI - Modified the tags to indicate your current app ie CF10

Answer (score 2):

Ok, apparently this wasn't as hard to test as I was making it out to be (thanks David Faber for the suggestion). By dumping out the variables scope in the cfc, we can easily see if the `cfmodule` call is "polluting" the cfc's variables scope. This occurs when the cfmodule uses its own `caller` scope.

As it turns out, this is easily remedied by "var scoping" any problematic variables in the method before making the cfmodule call. Indeed, this does the trick of preventing the `cfmodule` variables from bleeding through.

Without the var scoped variables in the method, the bleed over does indeed occur (as expected). This was my hunch, but I wanted to be totally sure considering the implications. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting ... what if you use an explicit `local` scope instead of `var` scoping? And what version of CF are you using (or are you using Railo or Lucee)?

Comment: Just tested `local` scope and it behaves the same way as `var` (also protecting from bleed through. I am on ACF 10,0,12,286680

Comment: *dumping out the variables scope in the cf* As a quick test, you also do a `structCount(variables)` at the start and end of a function. If the count increases, you know one or more variables was not local scoped.